# Notification is closing when webview is opening

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-notifications

My app has few activities and fragments. One of the activities is radio player. User can control player using a media notification (and a service). And it's working nice. But then I added to the radio activity a fragment with webview (site "chatovod"). And saw when I open this fragment (webview) my media notification is closing (but not service - music still playing). By the way other notifications (from the image activity) still showing.

```
class ChatovodFragment: Fragment() {

private lateinit var webView: WebView

companion object {
    fun newInstance(url: String): ChatovodFragment {
        val fragment = ChatovodFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString(BUNDLE_CHATOVOD_URL, url)
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack()
            } else {
                activity?.supportFragmentManager?.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    })
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chatovod, container, false)
    val url: String =
        if (arguments != null) {
            requireArguments().getString(BUNDLE_CHATOVOD_URL, "")
        } else
            ""
    webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.loadUrl(url)
    webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
    return view
}

class MyWebViewClient: WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): Boolean {
        view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
        return true
    }
}
```

The service code is big. So if you need it I could load it to other place.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my ignorance of English,but i hope you could understand what i am trying to anwser.

This question happened more than one place in my application.

In my application it is the audio focus make it.

Code:

```
systemService.abandonAudioFocus(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        }
    });
```

or other override method with it .

Do something in it.

Hope it helps you man.

Comment: It is the systemService: AudioManager systemService = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

Comment: Thanks! I will try it later when will home. Where you placed this code? In the webview or the player service ?